# Can quantum black hole be in superposition state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, wavefunction, quantum-gravity, superposition

Quantum black hole can have electric charge and angular momentum or spin, I am wondering if a quantum black hole can be described as a probability wavefunction or not? If so can it quantum tunnels too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no widely-accepted theory of quantum black holes, so any statements about their behavior are highly speculative. I think most physicists assume that a black hole probably does have a wavefunction, but what equation that wavefunction satisfies is not obvious or agreed on. Therefore discussion of scenarios like tunneling is not particularly productive.